# Get user info with JWT in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, local-storage, backend

I´m storing the user token in the localstorage after a user logs in, and i would like to know how i can use this token that is in the localstorage to fetch the user info.

**backend login.js**

```
module.exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ message: "Usuário não cadastrado!" });

    const isMatch = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email e/ou senha incorretos." });

    const token = tokenGenereator(user._id);

    return res.status(200).json({ result: user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

**frontend login.js**

```
export const login = (data, history) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const userData = await api.login(data);
      localStorage.setItem("userToken", JSON.stringify(userData.data.token));
      dispatch(
        setUser({
          fullname: userData.data.fullname,
          email: userData.data.email,
          isAuth: true,
        })
      );
      history.push("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
        dispatch(
          setNotification({
            variant: "danger",
            message: error.response.data.message,
          })
        );
      }
    }
  };
};
```

I pass the token to the backend

```
// i would pass the jwt to the function as a parameter
export const fetchUser = (data) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const user = await api.getUserData(data);
    console.log(user);
  };
};
```

And i recieve

```
module.exports.getCurrentUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;
  // i dont know what to do from here...
};
```

Comment: Can you share the API for fetch user info ? How the token send ?

Comment: Look the user up in the database? This question really has nothing to do with JWT nor React. Also, it's unusual to send a JWT as a request body like that. It's usually passed via an `Authorization` header or something similar.